# Java Activiti Variables

Tags: java, spring-mvc, activiti

I am learning Java Activiti in order to connect a process through Java Spring MVC.

I have used the Java Service Task and my code executes. What I want to do is when the process starts I want the client to send inputs. For example send a name. How is this possible through Java Activiti? I have tried all things but can't find what I need.

Also, I would like the process to output something.

Answer (score 1):

On what i could understand from your question, there are few options i could think of.

1. Create a webservice. In that, you can get GET/POST data from user. Then in service code, start the workflow using Acitviti API.
2. Create a form on Start event. Go through Properties of Start Event
3. Create a User task just after Start event. Get the input from user using form properties.